# How can I change the attribute in dataset of Fusionchart?

Tags: angularjs, charts, attributes, fusion

Hi I am implementing a chart in my Angularjs Application, You can see this plunker `http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/73xgmacm/` The thing which I want to achieve is to change the `value` attribute to `profit`. How can I do this ? I want to display `profit` not values.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days I finally find out the answer. The thing is You cannot change the `Fusionchart` attribute `value` but you can change the attribute of your API once you fetched. I used a loop after I fetched the API and replace the 'profit' attribute with `value` in this way I made the chart. Yes The thing which i had been ignoring was the use of 'variable' instead of scope. If you see this example you would understand [Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjuktamukherjee/45u56055/). I am sharing my code May be it helps someone else too.

Give below is my json array which i called `tps.json`

```
[
        {
            "index": "1",
            "variantoption": "fan-green",
            "company": "sk fans",
            "quantity": "650",
            "profit": "78296",
            "loss": "8457",
            "year": "2016"


        },
        {
            "index": "2",
            "variantoption": "fan-white",
            "company": "al ahmed fans",
            "quantity": "450",
            "profit": "78296",
            "loss": "8457",
            "year": "2016"

        },
        {
            "index": "3",
            "variantoption": "fan-purple",
            "company": "asia fans",
            "quantity": "350",
            "profit": "78296",
            "loss": "8457",
            "year": "2016"
        },
        {
            "index": "4",
            "variantoption": "fan-yellow",
            "company": "falcon fans",
            "quantity": "250",
            "profit": "78296",
            "loss": "8457",
            "year": "2016"
        }
    ]
```

and here is my controller

```
$http.get('js/tps.json').success(function (data) {
      var chartdata =    data;

        var arrLength = chartdata.length;
        console.log(arrLength);

        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
                if (chartdata[i]['profit'] && chartdata[i]['index']) {
                    chartdata[i].value = chartdata[i].profit;
                    delete chartdata[i].profit;

                   chartdata[i].label = chartdata[i].index;
                    delete chartdata[i].index;
                    console.log(chartdata);
                }
            }
            console.log(chartdata);

            FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            var tps = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'column2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '500',
                height: '300',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                    "caption": "Monthly",
                    "xaxisname": "Month",
                    "yaxisname": "Revenue",
                    "numberprefix": "$",
                    "showvalues": "1",
                    "animation": "1"
                },

                    "data" : chartdata
                }

            });


            tps.render();

        });
    }
    );

}
```

-Stay foolish stay hungry